# Is it possible to duplicate an entry as not enabled/live from the listing page?

Tags: craft3, admin

Is it possible to duplicate an entry as not enabled/live from the admin listing page? Just this means some user put pages live on the site that are just copies - they forget to quickly change it to disabled etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After talking with Brad in Craft support we came up with this to put in a plugin. So now when duplicate is called in the admin (list of entries) it is set to disabled. Normal Craft behaviour is to keep the same state as the entry being copied.

```
//if duplicate sets entry to not live / disabled 
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event) {
        $entry = $event->sender;

        // If the Entry is being duplicated.
        if ($entry->duplicateOf) {
            
            $entry->enabled = false;//set to disabled

        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `duplicateOf` is not sufficient to detect duplicates. A draft, provisional draft or revision being applied to the live entry will also have a `duplicateOf` property, so this will result in live entries being disabled on save (see this [issue on Github](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/10245) for reference).

To be sure the hook only applies to duplicated entries, you also need to check the [`updatingFromDerivative` property](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-elementtrait.html#updatingfromderivative) – if that is false, the entry is being duplicated.

Here's a complete working hook for Craft 3.7:

```php
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\ModelEvent;
use craft\helpers\ElementHelper;

Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function (ModelEvent $e) {
        $entry = $e->sender;
        if (ElementHelper::isDraftOrRevision($entry)) return;
        if (!$entry->duplicateOf || $entry->updatingFromDerivative) return;
        $entry->enabled = false;
    }
);
```

---

In Craft 4, duplicated entries will be disabled by default (see the [discussion on Github](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/10244) for reference).